# Как в тюпле инициализировать значение как nil?

Tags: swift

Я новичок в Swift и вот тренируюсь с примерами

Вот есть такой тюпл

```
let oneMore = (message : "message here", errorMessage : nil)
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если пишу вот так

```
let aa : String? = nil
let oneMore = (message : "message here", errorMessage : aa)
```

то все нормально

Как сразу в тюпле присвоить nil?

Comment: Закастить `nil` в `String?`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете при инициализации тюпла скормить ему `nil`, так как компилятор не знает какой должен быть тип в этом случае. Можете объявить так:

```
var oneMore: (message: String, errorMessage: String?) = (message : "message here", errorMessage : nil)
```

Можете как посоветовал VladD :

```
var oneMore = (message : "message here", errorMessage : nil as String?)
```